# "where in" in trigger after insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I must insert a new row in a table, with a text column that contains reference to another table's ids. Eg:
INSERT INTO table1 (reference, date) VALUES('23,24,25','2016-09-22');

My trigger should update table2.status where table2.id is one of table1.reference values. Now it's something like this:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `rim_ai` AFTER INSERT ON `table1` FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE table2 SET status = 11 WHERE id IN (NEW.reference);;
DELIMITER ;
```

But... I found status value changed only on the first row (eg. the one with ID 23).
If something is broken in my trigger it should update nothing at all!
Should I convert the reference field to something else than 'text'?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not your trigger that is broken, but your table design. You really should not store a series of values within a single field separated by a comma (or any other separator). You should store each individual reference - date pair in its own record.

Instead of

```
reference | date
23,24,25  |2016-09-22
```

have

```
reference | date
23        |2016-09-22
24        |2016-09-22
25        |2016-09-22
```

In this instance your trigger will work as expected. Although, I would rewrite the `where` clause slightly:

```
...WHERE id = NEW.reference
```

You could technically make the trigger work with the current data structure using multi-table update statement and `find_in_set()` function, but I do not recommend that.

The cause for the behaviour that your are experiencing is that the `id IN (NEW.reference)` expression is not evaluated as `id IN (23,24,25)` (set of 3 values in the `in` operator), but as `id IN ('23,24,25')` (single string containing the 3 numbers). MySQL silently converts the `'23,24,25'` string to number, which will results in the number 23 (comma after 23 cannot be interpreted as part of a number, so MySQL stops with the conversion a returns 23 as number). Hence only the record with id=23 is updated.

Comment: You're clearly right... I was lazily trying to workaround the creation of a referenced table. Thank you.